# Memory addressing and pointer exercises

Tags: c, pointers

Assume you have a 16 bit machine with 65536 bytes of memory. Ints are 2 bytes. Assume that variables are placed in memory contiguously in the order they are coded, starting at memory address 0x250. Given the following code segment:

```
int x = 30; 
int y = 50; 
int *px = &x;
int *py = &y;

printf("a) %x\n", px); 
printf("b) %x\n", py); 

px = py; 
printf("c) %d\n", *px); 
printf("d) %x\n", &px); 

x = 88; 
y = 14;

printf("e) %d\n", *px); 
printf("f) %d\n", *py);
```

Give the output of each printf statement.

They say to assume the memory addresses are allocated in ascending order.

I got

```
a) 252
b) 254
c) 30
d) 250
e) 88
f) 14
```

Are these correct?

Comment: Every answer you've given that is greater than 250 is incorrect.  They *might* be correct if you include a `0x` prefix, indicating they are hexadecimal values.

Comment: Homework questions are allowed if you show your own effort and where you are stuck.  People are more likely to give hints than solutions to homework to encourage learning.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart How are they wrong?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: Actually, since `printf` is using `%x`, this is what you'd see from the console.

Comment: If you dump a homework question without minimal effort to found the answer, no, it's not allowed.

Comment: @JPHamlett: He means you need to prefix 0x :-)

Comment: @ouah: He presents what he things are the answer.  It's OK.

Comment: @nneonneo Doh! Good call. Stupid teacher forgot the "0x" :-)

Comment: @JPHamlett: All but one of your answers is wrong, as far as I can tell. I would go over the sequence of steps more carefully. Hint: as a first pass, just allocate the variable addresses just so you know where everything is.

Comment: I think we're also supposed to assume that `sizeof(void*) == sizeof(int) == 2`.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: Yes 16 bit systems have typically had 16 bit pointers.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because homework marking.

Comment: I don't think any of them are correct except f.

Comment: Agree with @kaylum.  I totally missed that the 30 and 50 are assigned as decimal but printed as hex.  Also intuitively but incorrectly allocated space for a return address when initially thinking the first two were correct :-)

Comment: @EricJ. Would the first variable be assigned to 0x250 or 0x252?

Comment: @JPHamlett: You can solve this with paper and pencil. Write all your variables, their addresses and values and manually perform each line of code.

Comment: @JPHamlett: `Assume that variables are placed in memory contiguously in the order they are coded, starting at memory address 0x250`

Comment: @MartinJames: Homework questions (that don't just dump the assignment) are allowed.  OP shows effort http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/286643/141172

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Assume that variables are placed in memory contiguously in the order they are coded, starting at memory address 0x250

Let's follow nneonneo's hint, and "as a first pass, just allocate the variable addresses just so you know where everything is."

This should start you off on the right foot:

```
int x = 30;               // &x  = 0x250
int y = 50;               // &y  = 0x252
int *px = &x;             // &px = 0x254
int *py = &y;             // &py = 0x256
```

Now a little guidance:

```
printf("a) %x\n", px);    // These both print the *value* of the pointers 
printf("b) %x\n", py);    // themselves (in other words, the address to which
                          // they point).
                          // Note: they're printed in hexadecimal
                          // (unfortunately with no prefix).

px = py;                  // The *value* of py is assigned to px.
                          // Now they both point to the same thing.


printf("c) %d\n", *px);   // This "de-references" px. In other words, it
                          // reads the value at the address px points to.


printf("d) %x\n", &px);   // This prints the *address* of the pointer px.
                          // Hint: can this change during program execution?

x = 88;                   // Simple integer assignments
y = 14;

printf("e) %d\n", *px);   // Same logic as c)

printf("f) %d\n", *py);   // Same logic as c)
```

Answers (for those who want to check their answers, or cheaters):

> a) 250
> b) 252
> c) 50
> d) 254
> e) 14
> f) 14

Comment: Also, OP be careful about what is a decimal value and what is a hex value.

Comment: Directed at OP.  Edited my previous comment for clarity.

Comment: Nice. Learnt how to post "spoiler text" as well!